# Filtering aerospike LLIST

Tags: php, udf, aerospike

Can anyone please show me how to filter an Aerospike LLIST bin not by the key and return all the result using PHP.

In my case the bin 'notes' is containing many rows of key, title, desc & category. I can retrieve all rows using the following code but
I need to do a filter on the category and get the results of only those within the same category. If udf is needed please assist to show me the udf code as well and how to apply the filter to get the results.

```
$db = new Aerospike($config, false);<br/>
$key = $db->initKey('mynamespace', 'myset', $userid);<br/>
$list = new \Aerospike\LDT\LList($db, $key, 'notes');<br/>
$status = $list->scan($results);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to modify the UDF as follows and it works.

```
  local category_filters = {} 
  function category_filters.filterBy(element,val)            
  if element['category'] == val[1] then
    return element   
  else
    return nil   
  end 
end 
return category_filters
```

Invoked by

```
$status = $list->scan($results, 'category_filters', 'filterBy', array($category));
```

Answer (score 2):

The [LList.scan](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php/blob/master/doc/aerospike_llist.md) method has an optional module name, function name pair of parameters, allowing you to call a Lua function to filter each element.

There's an [example PHP script](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php/blob/master/examples/ldt/map_elements.php#L220-L229) provided with the client repo, which calls an [example Lua](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php/blob/master/examples/ldt/lua/keyfilters.lua#L3-L15) module:

```
function keyfilters.even_filter(element)
    local remainder = -1
    if type(element) == "number" then
        remainder = element % 2
    elseif (getmetatable(element) == getmetatable(map())) and element['key'] then
        remainder = element['key'] % 2
    end
    if remainder == 0 then
        return element
    else
        return nil
    end
end
```

Is invoked by

```
$rental_history->scan($elements, 'keyfilters', 'even_filter');
```